# How to start to resize the bootcamp disk on Mac Book pro?

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp

At the moment, I am using Mac Book Pro with Mac OSX 10.6 (Snow leopard, 180 GB) and Windows 7 Professional in boot camp (50 GB). I plans to increase size of boot camp now because I need more spaces for my office application.

I have search around to find out the best way to do this. but I don't sure how to do. Do I have to...

1. Enter OSX
2. Use Disk Utility -> Boot camp assistant
3. Resize partition like we did before to install a fresh Windows OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to:

2. use disk utility to create a disk image of the drive
3. Back this up somewhere
4. Resize the partition
5. Use disk utility to restore the image.

hope this helps.