# Bootcamp - Resizing windows 7 partition?

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, partitioning

I'm using a Mac Book Pro with Bootcamp to run Windows 7. I have recently ran out of space on my windows partition.

I tried using disk utility on my Snow Leopard install disc but it wouldn't let to change the partition sizes.

So, how can I change the partitions on a Bootcamped Mac Book Pro?

Comment: Just some ideas from google... 1. Winclone to copy the windows partition, and CampTune to resize it. http://news.cnet.com/8301-13512_3-10065233-23.html ...2. Snow leopard disk utility (from the install CD) or gparted. http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=10463299 ...never tried this, so good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As covered here: [How to start to resize the bootcamp disk on Mac Book pro?](https://superuser.com/questions/80681/how-to-start-to-resize-the-bootcamp-disk-on-mac-book-pro/80682#80682)

you should be able to:

1. use disk utility to create a disk image of the drive
2. Back this up somewhere
3. Resize the partition
4. Use disk utility to restore the
   image.

Not sure if this is be best way as I haven't done this is a LONG time.

Hope this helps